# new and old jquery version --> how to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html page that is using jquery and boostrap with some old javascript. If I am using this script:  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
 It will make below error. It means some old javascript has error. What should i do? Is there a way to amend this? The above jquery script link is needed as some new features need this.

[image: Old javascript error that are using old jquery version]

Comment: you want [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) perhaps?

Comment: I think you missed to include jQuery UI. `.tabs()` is not a jquery core feature. it is added to jquery when you include jquery ui.

Comment: Sorry, I have mixed sth up. Now I added this link. Same error happened.  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js'></script>

Comment: @AMMA Can you create a live example?